# getting kafka log end offset from jmx

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to build out a real-time monitoring solution that will stretch across n number of kafka clusters. One of things I'm trying to do is to calculate lag by using the internal `__consumer_offsets` topic and the `kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogEndOffset` mbean.

What I'm curious about is that, lets say I have 5 brokers in my kafka cluster, do I need to collect the LogEndOffset from each broker and do a max to get the LogEndOffset, or will just getting it from one suffice?

A side question, if I do a min on the LogEndOffset, would that give me the high water mark then?

Comment: You could use this mbean and 'LogStartOffset' mbean to calculate the current message count for a topic, but it's possible to calculate the lag by doing the same thing for __consumer_offsets. One reason is that if two groups happen to be hashed into the same partition(bucket) of this topic, you get no chance to tell how many log entries each group writes to the topic.

Comment: @amethystic, I didn't quite understand this part `One reason is that if two groups happen to be hashed into the same partition(bucket) of this topic, you get no chance to tell how many log entries each group writes to the topic`

Comment: My understanding is that you want to retrieve the lag for some consumer group(say, groupA) by calculating the LEOs of __consumer_offsets, right? If it is the case, then it is possible that the offsets for another consumer group (say, groupB) are also written into the same partition of __consumer_offsets, so you cannot calculate the lag for groupA then. Do I make myself clear this time?

Comment: Ok...I see what you mean, but I could still do the calc by topic AND group then, right?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the calc by analysing the log entries of __consumer_offsets?

Comment: @amethystic yes, I'm combining data from that topic (`__consumer_offsets`) AND the `kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogEndOffset` mbean. The topic gives me the position of the consumers and the mbean gives the end offset of each log by partition...I believe...

Answer (score 0):

From JMX exporter you can use below query :

```
sum(max(kafka_log_logendoffset{topic="your_topic_name"}) by (topic,partition))
```

Comment: 2 questions
1. What is the difference of monitoring consumer group lag log-end-offset in jmx vs __consumer_offsets? It seems like a lot of solutions have been using combinations of both
2. Am I able to use regex patterns to capture more than a single topic?
eg. sum(max(kafka_log_logendoffset{topic=~"my-prefix.*"}) by (topic,partition))